# How do I use Spark's Feature Importance on Random Forest?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel) for [Random Forests](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/mllib-ensembles.html) does not include feature importances. However, it is listed on the [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5133) as resolved and is in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tree/impl/RandomForest.scala). [HERE](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forests) also says "The main differences between this API and the original MLlib ensembles API are:

- support for DataFrames and ML Pipelines
- separation of classification vs. regression
- use of DataFrame metadata to distinguish continuous and categorical
  features
- more functionality for random forests: **estimates of feature
  importance**, as well as the predicted probability of each class
  (a.k.a. class conditional probabilities) for classification."

However, I cannot figure out a syntax that works to call this new feature.

```
scala> model
res13: org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel = 
TreeEnsembleModel classifier with 10 trees

scala> model.featureImportances
<console>:60: error: value featureImportances is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel
              model.featureImportances
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the new Random Forests. Check your imports.
The OLD:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel
```

The NEW Random Forests use:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier
```

[This S.O. answer provides code for extracting the importances.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42003497/1290485)

[This S.O. answer explains the sparse vector that is returned.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37881813/1290485)

Comment: with the new imports (RandomForestClassificationModel) - how do you train a model? @Climbs_lika_Spyder

Comment: @Yaeli778, there is a good example of how to train the model at https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-ensembles.html

Comment: Can you point to how to get the featureImportance from pyspark?

Comment: Could you tell us what to DO with the feature importances? They are a big SparseVector and aren't interpretable. How do you make them into something useful?