# Spark ML VectorAssembler returns strange output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am experiencing a very strange behaviour from `VectorAssembler` and I was wondering if anyone else has seen this.

My scenario is pretty straightforward. I parse data from a `CSV` file where I have some standard `Int` and `Double` fields and I also calculate some extra columns. My parsing function returns this:

```
val joined = countPerChannel ++ countPerSource //two arrays of Doubles joined
(label, orderNo, pageNo, Vectors.dense(joinedCounts))
```

My main function uses the parsing function like this:

```
val parsedData = rawData.filter(row => row != header).map(parseLine)
val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(parsedData).toDF("label", "orderNo", "pageNo","joinedCounts")
```

I then use a `VectorAssembler` like this:

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
                           .setInputCols(Array("orderNo", "pageNo", "joinedCounts"))
                           .setOutputCol("features")

val assemblerData = assembler.transform(data)
```

So when I print a row of my data before it goes into the `VectorAssembler` it looks like this:

```
[3.2,17.0,15.0,[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,2.0]]
```

After the transform function of VectorAssembler I print the same row of data and get this:

```
[3.2,(18,[0,1,6,9,14,17],[17.0,15.0,3.0,1.0,4.0,2.0])]
```

What on earth is going on? What has the `VectorAssembler` done? I 've double checked all the calculations and even followed the simple Spark examples and cannot see what is wrong with my code. Can you?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is nothing strange about the output. Your vector seems to have lots of zero elements thus `spark` used it’s sparse representation.

To explain further :

It seems like your vector is composed of 18 elements (dimension).

This indices `[0,1,6,9,14,17]` from the vector contains non zero elements which are in order `[17.0,15.0,3.0,1.0,4.0,2.0]`

Sparse Vector representation is a way to save computational space thus easier and faster to compute. More on Sparse representation [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-sparse-matrices-used-for-What-is-its-application-in-machine-learning/answer/Elias-Abou-Haydar?srid=agpP&share=a00c223d).

Now of course you can convert that sparse representation to a dense representation but it comes at a cost.

In case you are interested in getting feature importance, thus I advise you to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37881813/3415409).

Comment: Can I change that?

Comment: Also I am using the LinearRegression algorithm and want to get coefficients for each input. Does this sparse representation make it harder to get those coefficients?

Comment: It doesn't make it harder. You can convert a sparse vector to a dense vector since I believe it would be just a one vector output with a simple map a zip between the indices and elements.

Comment: I'm on my mobile phone, I can't code that now but it's a one liner piece of code.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying this. So when I get my coefficients output will I get all the coefficients for each of the inputs? Or will I get a different representation?

Comment: Exactly unless one feature's coefficient is zero.

Comment: Yes of course. Thanks so much for your input. I will try again and see how it goes

Comment: Your welcome. You might find an old answer of line concerning variable importance and random forest that might help you get there faster