# Exception while trying to explain model with MMLSpark's scala LIME library

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to explain the predictions made by my XGboost model using MMLSparks Lime package for scala.

This is my first time using LIME library, I am able to perform a fit operation on the dataset and when I am trying to perform the transform operation, the program stops with an exception,

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector`

I have around 200 features and many of them contain zero as its feature value.

Comment: I have the same issue even when I convert each column to double. I am able to resolve when I convert each zero value to 0.0000001

Comment: yep, this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely using [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) to create your feature vector column. The transform function outputs a **sparse vector** if there are lots of zeros in your feature set to save computational space. This causes the error for LIME.

More info on VectorAssembler output - [Spark ML VectorAssembler returns strange output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505805/spark-ml-vectorassembler-returns-strange-output)

The solution is to convert the column back to a **dense vector** in order for mmlspark LIME to interpret.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

val asDense = udf((v: Vector) => v.toDense)

featuresDF.withColumn("features", asDense(col("features")))
```

Then you can fit your model.

Comment: Yes, i was using VectorAssembler! Thank you.