# Spark VectorAssembler creating a dictionary from features

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having trouble with `VectorAssembler` in PySpark.

## Task

I have a bunch of data (all numerical) that describes the customer base for a phone company (monthly bills, gender, etc.). On datum can be seen here:

[image: Customer Data]

My goal is to try to predict if a customer will churn (leave the service).

## Method

In pursuit of this goal, I implemented the following code:

```python
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

ignore = ['Churn_indexed', 'customerID']
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[x for x in df_num.columns if x not in ignore],
 outputCol='Independent Features')

df_final = vectorAssembler.transform(df)
```

Where I have made a `VectorAssembler` to ignore customerID (irrelevant) and churn (to be predicted).

## Error

I then printed `df_final` to ensure it looked as expected as saw the following, where the red dots indicate rows that are of the expected form. The remaining rows do not have the expected form:

[image: Final Dataframe]

For some reason some of the rows have "20" at the beginning followed by a list. I should note that there are 20 features (including Churn and excluding CustomerID) which is perhaps where this pre-appended 20 comes from? I printed an incorrect row and a correct row and **it looks like for the incorrect ones the assembler turned the features into a dictionary**?

[image: Bad and good data]

#### CSV

I opened the CSV and tried looking for extra spaces or bad formatting and could not recognize a pattern for determining what ended up being VectorAssembled properly and what did not.

Has anyone else run into this issue? I've been troubleshooting for a long time to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the VectorAssembler automatically converts rows with many non-zeros (>= half from what I can tell) to their sparse form as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505805/spark-ml-vectorassembler-returns-strange-output)