# In PySpark ML, how can I interpret the SparseVector returned by a pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.featureImportances?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have created and am debugging a PySpark ML [RandomForestClassificationModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel) which was of course created by calling  `pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.fit()`. I want to interpret the feature vectors returned by the [RandomForestClassificationModel.featureImportances](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.featureImportances) property. They are a [SparseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector).

As you can see in the notebook below, I had to transform my features in several stages to get them into the final `Features_vec` that fed the algorithm. What I want is a list of features keyed by the feature type and column. How can I use the SparseVector of features to get to a list of feature importances along with feature names, or some other format that is interpretable?

The code is in a Jupyter Notebook [here](https://github.com/rjurney/Agile_Data_Code_2/blob/master/ch09/Debugging%20Prediction%20Problems.ipynb). Skip to the end.

This shouldn't be specific to PySpark, so if you know a Scala solution, please chime in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Random Forest Feature Importance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878519/spark-random-forest-feature-importance). I have written a small explanation at the end of my answer.

Comment: Not a duplicate, as the question says I need to interpret the feature importances of features that went through a StringIndexer.